# OpenCV python replacing white area of image

Tags: python, opencv

```
for i in range(25, 665):
  for j in range(55, 690): 
    pixel = background[i,j]
    whitePixel = [255,255,255]
    if np.array_equal(pixel,whitePixel):
      background[i,j] = rightsize[i-25,j-55]
```

when I do this code I get an image with ugly edges like this-

[image]

does anyone know how I can fix this and get it right? I dont understand Why it is doing this I have even tried adjusting the area of the rectangle so it was a little bigger than the white area and it still did this-

original background image-

[image]

now, the other image (rightsize) is just an image of the coin, which I cropped out in a perfect square around the coin, and resized to try and fit perfectly in a same sized square around that white circle, and replace the white parts with the coin, but for some reason the edges turn out like that. I have had this same problem before when doing a double loop like this to replace pixels.

Comment: I think it would be helpful for us to understand your issue if you could also upload the original background image and the coin image.